# Conditional Lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, conditional-statements

I want to apply a condition, after I passed another condition like this:

```
List<Entity> GetByCondition()
{
  If(dateConditionEnabled)
    {
      Repository.Get(i=>i.start<=datetime.Now && i.EndDate<=DateTime.Now);
    }
  else
    {
        Repository.Get();
    }
}
```

I want to apply "If" condition, in the lambda I used in Get method.

Any idea?

-Regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `Get()` equivalent to `Get( i => true)`? In this case you can use:

```
List<Entity> GetByCondition()
{
      return Repository.Get(!dateConditionEnabled || i=>i.start<=datetime.Now && i.EndDate<=DateTime.Now);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not

```
List<Entity> GetByCondition()
{
      return Repository.Get(i=>!i.dateConditionEnabled || i.start<=datetime.Now && i.EndDate<=DateTime.Now);
}
```

?

Comment: Thank you Hamlet, Henrik answered first. but the first part, !i.dateConditionEnabled of your post is correct.

Comment: Is 'dateConditionEnabled' a member of the repository entry or is it a part of the class which contains GetByCondition()?  If a part of the class then i => !i.dateConditionEnabled will give an error.

Comment: dateConditionEnabled is a property of my entity, but no, there is no error here :)